# Fluid transition when displaying a div using tailwind

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

I have a calendar, built using html, tailwind css and javascript.

[image]

This is the code structure of the calendar (added arbitrary classes for explanation purposes):

```
<main>
    <div class='calendar'>
      ....
    </div>
    <div class='hidden calendar-day-details'
      ....
    </div>
</main>
```

And this is how my code actually looks like, with according tailwind classes:

```
<main class="max-w-auto shadow-2xl shadow-[#16093E] flex items-stretch">
    <div class="bg-[#230F61] rounded-md px-10 py-6 shadow-2xl" id="calendar-wrapper">
      ....
    </div>
    <div id="show-details" class="bg-[#1D0958] rounded-r-md px-10 py-6 shadow-2xl text-white transition-all hidden transform-gpu w-0" >
    ....
    </div>
</main>
```

By default, div with `id="show-details"` is hidden, and displayed only when clicking on a certain date, using JavaScript
[image]

To achieve that, I'm adding next classes: `w-72`, `block`, `scale-100`, and removing `w-0`, `hidden`, `scale-0` classes, and when clicking outside, I'm doing the vice versa.

So my question is how to do this smoothly, using tailwind, because it has to be something related to transition, because right now, when I click on a date element, the date details div just pops up, while I would like to animate the transition of its width's growth (example: ChatGPT side menu toggle).

This is my JavaScript code:

```
const calendarWrapper = document.getElementById('calendar-wrapper');
const clickableDates = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable:not(.empty)');

clickableDates.forEach(dateElement => {
    dateElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // other logic

        calendarWrapper.classList.add('rounded-r-none')

        dateDisplay.classList.remove('w-0', 'hidden', 'scale-0');
        dateDisplay.classList.add('w-72', 'block', 'scale-100'); 
    });
});


document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('clickable') && !dateDisplay.contains(event.target)) {
        clickableDates.forEach(element => {
            element.classList.remove('bg-[#DF15ED]');
        });
        dateDisplay.classList.add('w-0', 'hidden');
        dateDisplay.classList.remove('w-72', 'block');
        calendarWrapper.classList.remove('rounded-r-none')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No transitions happen because no transitions run on the same frame that `display: none` is added/removed. You could consider applying `visibility: hidden` instead which does largely the same thing (but the element still takes up layout space):

```js
const calendarWrapper = document.getElementById('calendar-wrapper');
const clickableDates = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable:not(.empty)');

const dateDisplay = document.getElementById('show-details');

clickableDates.forEach(dateElement => {
  dateElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // other logic

    calendarWrapper.classList.add('rounded-r-none')

    dateDisplay.classList.remove('w-0', 'invisible', 'scale-0');
    dateDisplay.classList.add('w-72', 'scale-100');
  });
});


document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains('clickable') && !dateDisplay.contains(event.target)) {
    clickableDates.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove('bg-[#DF15ED]');
    });
    dateDisplay.classList.add('w-0', 'invisible', 'scale-0');
    dateDisplay.classList.remove('w-72');
    calendarWrapper.classList.remove('rounded-r-none')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<main class="max-w-auto shadow-2xl shadow-[#16093E] flex items-stretch">
  <div class="bg-[#230F61] rounded-md px-10 py-6 shadow-2xl" id="calendar-wrapper">
    <button class="clickable">clickable</button>
  </div>
  <div id="show-details" class="bg-[#1D0958] rounded-r-md px-10 py-6 shadow-2xl text-white transition-all invisible transform-gpu w-0 scale-0">
    ....
  </div>
</main>
```

You could look at using some sort of `position: absolute` manipulations if you need the element to not affect layout.

The transition can still be unsmooth due to the `width` being transitioned. This is caused by layout calculations on every animation frame and on lower-end devices, could cause the transition to run less than the standard 60 frames-per-second. Typically, you'd want to keep to animating `transform` and `opacity` only, since no layout calculations happen: https://web.dev/animations-guide/#triggers

This could be an alternative, more performant transition to get you started:

```js
const calendarWrapper = document.getElementById('calendar-wrapper');
const clickableDates = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable:not(.empty)');

const dateDisplay = document.getElementById('show-details');

clickableDates.forEach(dateElement => {
  dateElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // other logic

    calendarWrapper.classList.add('rounded-r-none')

    dateDisplay.classList.remove('invisible', 'scale-75', 'opacity-0');
  });
});


document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains('clickable') && !dateDisplay.contains(event.target)) {
    clickableDates.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove('bg-[#DF15ED]');
    });
    dateDisplay.classList.add('invisible', 'scale-75', 'opacity-0');
    calendarWrapper.classList.remove('rounded-r-none')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<main class="max-w-auto shadow-2xl shadow-[#16093E] flex items-stretch">
  <div class="bg-[#230F61] rounded-md px-10 py-6 shadow-2xl" id="calendar-wrapper">
    <button class="clickable">clickable</button>
  </div>
  <div id="show-details" class="bg-[#1D0958] rounded-r-md px-10 py-6 shadow-2xl text-white transition-all invisible transform-gpu w-72 scale-75 opacity-0 origin-left">
    ....
  </div>
</main>
```